# Why is a red piece of cloth tied to the vehicle?

Tags: practice, puja, superstitions

When worshiping a vehicle I have seen many times that a red piece of cloth is tied to it. What is the actual reason behind tying a red colored cloth and some bangles with it?

Please share answers only on scriptural basis and don't post pseudoscience answers like it's because red has highest wavelength or something, it wards of evils, prevents accidents, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by worshipping a vehicle?  You mean the ritual you do when you get a new car?

Comment: Do you mean [this peice of cloth](http://saishraddhasamagri.com/image/cache/data/Mala%20Cloth/MATAJI%20CHUNI/MATAJI%20KI%20CHUNI-650x489.jpg)?

Comment: include lemons tied to vehicle also.? please.